# How to make `trap` know if the EXIT is after successful program finish or because of premature as an error or something

Tags: shell-script, exit-status, trap

**PROBLEM:**

I have a shell program that I have been writing but I can't find out how to make sure that `trap` is trapping for cleanup at the end or because of a error in some command, it cleans up either way.

*Here is the code:*

```
################################### Successful exit then this cleanup ###########################################################3

successfulExit()
{
    IFS=$IFS_OLD
    cd "$HOME" || { echo "cd $HOME failed"; exit 155; }
    rm -rf /tmp/svaka || { echo "Failed to remove the install directory!!!!!!!!"; exit 155; }
}
###############################################################################################################################33
####### Catch the program on successful exit and cleanup
trap successfulExit EXIT
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I make `trap` only `trap EXIT` on program finish?

*Here is the full script:*

[debianConfigAwsome.5.3.sh](https://pastebin.com/SkexvPQL)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On entry to the `EXIT` trap, `$?` contains the exit status. That's the same value you'd find as `$?` after calling this script in another shell: either the argument passed to `exit` (truncated to the range 0–255) or the return status of the preceding command. In the case of an exit due to `set -e`, it's the return status of the command that triggered the implicit `exit`.

Usually you should save `$?` and exit again with the same status.

```sh
cleanup () {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "Aborted by $1"
  elif [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failure (status $status)"
  else
    echo "Success"
  fi
}
trap 'status=$?; cleanup; exit $status' EXIT
trap 'trap - HUP; cleanup SIGHUP; kill -HUP $$' HUP
trap 'trap - INT; cleanup SIGINT; kill -INT $$' INT
trap 'trap - TERM; cleanup SIGTERM; kill -TERM $$' TERM
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into an issue with the accepted answer, where `cleanup` could end up being called multiple times. Resolved it by moving the clearing of the traps inside the cleanup function:

```
cleanup () {
  local exit_status=$?
  local exit_signal="$1"
  if [ -n "$exit_signal" ]; then
    echo "Aborted by $1"
  elif [ $exit_status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failure (status $exit_status)"
  else
    echo "Success"
  fi
  trap - EXIT HUP INT TERM
  return $exit_status
}

trap cleanup EXIT
trap 'cleanup SIGHUP; kill -HUP $$' HUP
trap 'cleanup SIGINT; kill -INT $$' INT
trap 'cleanup SIGTERM; kill -TERM $$' TERM
```

Comment: I think you can combine those `trap -` commands into one: `trap - EXIT HUP INT TERM`

Comment: True, I forgot you could combine signal specs like that when the trap command was the same for all of them (including clearing the trap). Fixed!